# Null point Exceptions are there

Tags: exception, null, point

These are the error I am getting

[image: 1]

All these red highlighted part are the error:

[image: All these red highlighted part are the error]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

Well...as far as I can see you wanted to invoke a virtual method...anywhere.

And your exception says that it should point to NULL...which is ok I guess, because everywhere else would be fatal.

Comment: as error are ocuring from looper.java ans handler..java......as they are creates by default by system

Comment: Well I don't know your code and so I can't tell you what steps you need. The only thing I could tell you is to look where this error accuse [...getString(j...??)] and that you shouldn't invoke a virtual method. I know it's not a satisfying answer, but maybe the link of tkausl could help you more.